# Mapstruct : Code too large error in Impl class generated for enum conversion

Tags: java, enums, mapstruct

I'm quite new to mapstruct. I have multiple enum classes(which are generated dynamically through swagger-codegen) in a project which are having around 1k to 1.5K of values. Once Impl class has been generated after *mvn clean install* for the mapper interface, I get compilation error **code too large for try statement** because of the methods for converting those enums are of around 3K lines (that's what I'm assuming right now as I can’t find any other reason).

I've tried creating mapping for those specific enums but that is also not working. Also since its config based code generation is there any way to restrict/split large methods?

Answer (score 1):

> A single method in a Java class may be at most 64KB of bytecode.

**Is there any way to restrict/split large methods?**

**No**, please optimize your own code or program.
Large enum should be replaced by `.properties` file or data in db.